# JavaScript function encapsulation outside the object

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, object, encapsulation

**Please see the following script:**

```
var x = function(param){
    this.data=param;

    this.y = function(){
        alert(this.data)
    }

    return this;
}

/*
    x.prototype.z = function(){
        alert(this.data);
    }
*/

x(123).y();
x(123).z(); // This should behave same as y()
```

When I call ***x(123).y()*** then message displays ***123***. The function ***y()*** declared inside ***x()***

Now I want to declare another function ***z()*** which will reside outside ***x()*** but will behave same as ***y()*** [associate with ***x()***]

Is it possible? If possible how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `new` when calling `x()`. Otherwise, `this` within the function body will refer to the global object (`window` in browser contexts) and not an instance of `x`.

That's the reason why calling `z()` (after un-commenting the code) doesn't work. Calling `y()` only works by coincidence as you create a global variable `data`, whose value will be overwritten by the next call to `x()`.

---

I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish, and from what I can see, it most likely isn't a good idea. Anyway, here's an example of how to get rid of explicit `new` when creating objects:

```
var x = function(param){
    // add missing `new`:
    if(!(this instanceof x))
        return new x(param);

    this.data=param;

    this.y = function(){
        alert(this.data)
    }
}


x.prototype.z = function(){
    alert(this.data);
}

x(123).y();
x(456).z();
```

Comment: I know about the new keyword issue.

But I need to have the solution without using new.

Any more IDEA?

Comment: sorry, if you don't want to use `new`, you can't use `prototype` so you'll have to add the `z()` method to all objects manually...

Comment: added an example of how to 'hide' the `new` and use a simple function call for object instantiation

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, and your commented-out `z` function should work as is if you fix how you're creating `x`s.

Note that your function `y` doesn't have to be declared inside the constructor if it's only dealing with instance properties (which in your code it is), and doing so has a significant memory cost (every instance gets *its own copy* of that function).  You only want to do that if you absolutely have to for major data hiding reasons, given the costs involved.

Edit: Sorry, I missed something:  You're missing the `new` keyword, your examples should be:

```
new x(123).y();
new x(123).z();
```

...and your constructor shouldn't return `this`.

Complete example:

```
var x = function(param) {

    this.data=param;

    // Doesn't have to be in the constructor, and you should
    // avoid it unless you're doing something with major
    // data hiding a'la Crockford
    this.y = function() {
        alert(this.data)
    }
}

x.prototype.z = function() {
    alert(this.data);
}

new x(123).y();
new x(123).z();
```

[This is the Crockford article](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) I mention above, but again, it has big memory implications.

Comment: I know about the new keyword issue.

But I need to have the solution without using new.

Any more IDEA?

Comment: Don't use `this` if you don't want to use `new`.

Comment: @Saiful: Wrap the whole thing up in another function that does the `new` for you and returns the result. You need `new` for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function generator( param ) {
    this.data = param;
    this.y = function() {
        alert( this.data )
    }
}

generator.prototype.z = function() {
    alert( this.data );
}

x = new generator( 3 );
x.y()
x.z()
```

Not sure if this is what you want, but this is a constructor named `generator` which returns an object, and a prototypal method is defined outside of it with the `new` keyword.

As others stated:

- you don't need to return `this` in the constructor
- you call it with the `new` keyword
- all methods declared with `this` are public unless you use `var` in which case they become private